# SQL Error [1038] [HY001]: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, buffer

I have created a stored procedure in mysql for searching articles.
So when I want to call it, I get this error.

SQL Error [1038] [HY001]: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size

My code purpose is to sort articles first based on title relatively and then based on description relatively.

Also after increasing buffer size(and restarting mysql service and then call sp again) I get this error:
SQL Error [S1000]: Could not retrieve transaction read-only status from server

```
create PROCEDURE art_usp_Article_Search(in SearchTerm varchar(200),in SortColumn varchar(100),in SortOrder varchar(5),in PageNumber int,in PageSize int)
BEGIN
    
    
    DECLARE StartRow INT;
    DECLARE EndRow INT;
    declare NSortColumn varchar(100);
    declare NSortOrder varchar(100);
    -- calculate the starting and ending of records
    SET NSortColumn = LOWER(IFNULL(SortColumn, ''));
    SET NSortOrder = LOWER(IfNULL(SortOrder, ''));
    SET StartRow = (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize  ;    
    SET EndRow = (PageNumber * PageSize)+1      ;   
    
    WITH CTETitleResult AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
            CASE 
                WHEN (@SortColumn = 'title' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN title
                WHEN (@SortColumn = 'date' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN date
            end
         ) AS RowNumber
        , COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount
        ,id,code,categoryId ,title,shortDescription ,description ,tags ,content,date,time,typeId,isActive,isSpecial,visited,author,imageId,statusId,created_by,updated_by,created_at,updated_at
        FROM art_article aa 
        WHERE isActive = 1
         AND (
                 (IfNULL(SearchTerm, '') = '' OR title LIKE CONCAT('%', SearchTerm, '%'))
            )
    ),CTEDescriptionResult AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
            CASE 
                WHEN (@SortColumn = 'title' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN title
                WHEN (@SortColumn = 'date' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN date
            end
         ) AS RowNumber
        , COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount
        ,id,code,categoryId ,title,shortDescription ,description ,tags ,content,date,time,typeId,isActive,isSpecial,visited,author,imageId,statusId,created_by,updated_by,created_at,updated_at
        FROM art_article aa 
        WHERE isActive = 1
         AND (
                 (IfNULL(SearchTerm, '') = '' OR shortDescription LIKE CONCAT('%', SearchTerm, '%'))
            )
    )
    SELECT *
        FROM CTETitleResult
        WHERE RowNumber > StartRow AND RowNumber < EndRow
        union       
        SELECT *
        FROM CTEDescriptionResult
        WHERE RowNumber > StartRow AND RowNumber < EndRow
        ORDER BY RowNumber;
    
END

call art_usp_Article_Search('','title','asc',1,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution

Just run mysql query

SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 256000000 // It'll reset after server restart

To set permanent

Edit below file and add

sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

sort_buffer_size = 256000000

sudo service mysql restart